# Can't import the QUDT unit Ontology into Protege

Tags: import, ontology, protege

I'm trying to import the QUDT unit Ontology (http://qudt.org/vocab/unit/) into my Ontology via the "direct imports" import in Protege. I paste the link to the raw ontology (http://qudt.org/2.1/vocab/unit) as the web address into the wizard, but it doesn't seem to recognize the Ontology. I tried the same with the main QUDT Ontology (http://qudt.org/2.1/schema/qudt) and it worked.

If I download the ttl file of the unit Ontology and the open the file via Protege it works just fine. The Ontology loads and everything works. However if I try to "direct import" the Ontology, even as a local file, it doesn't work.

Am I overlooking something?

Does anyone have an idea how to import the QUDT unit ontology into my ontology?

Thanks!